# Creating a list in R when I have another list that contains relevant indexes

Tags: r

An analogy of the problem I'm facing is growth phases of butterflies. Lets say there are 4 stages to go from being conceived to death. I have an array which defines the days at which the transition happens, and I have an equation which tells me the size of the larva/butterfly/whatever at each of these phases (the analogy isnt exact but its close enough)

I.e.:

```
days <- c(5,20,50,100)
#We have transitions on day 5, 20, 50, 100
#Using a linear size=m*day+c, we calculate the size of the creature
base_size <- c(1,10,11,20)
#This defines the c in the equation above
daily_growth_rate <- c(0.01,0.03,0.03,0.05)
#This defines the gradient, m
```

I also  have the (redundant, admittedly) information of the relative number of days between stages:

```
rel_days <- c(0,15,30,50)
#This is just t_n-t_(n-1) from the days array
```

What I would like to do is populate an array with all the days in question (which is easily done):

```
output_days <- c(days[1]:days[length(days)])
```

But then I need to populate the size on each of these days as per the equation above

The way I envision (currently) the final code to look like, is something like this:

```
size <- daily_base_size+relative_day*growth_rate
```

But I'm not quite sure how to populate these variables.

For example, relative days would look like:

```
relative_day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1,2,3......30,1,2....50)
```

Comment: Perhaps `relative_day <- sequence(rel_days)` and `rep(base_size, rel_days)+relative_day*rep(daily_growth_rate, rel_days)`

Comment: lol. I knew there was an easy way to do it. R, you're fricking awesome.

Comment: This does also leave open how I then assign daily_base_size and growth_rate, for example daily_base_size would look like: `daily_base_size<-c(0.01 [15 times], 0.03 [30 times]) etc`

Comment: Use the `rep` as in the solution posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sequence` to create the `relative_day`

```
relative_day <- sequence(rel_days)
```

and then use this in the equation after replicating the 'base_size' and 'daily_growth_rate'.

```
rep(base_size, rel_days)+relative_day*rep(daily_growth_rate, rel_days)
```

Comment: Hello.
So the problem I have is that it is filling slightly incorrectly. The functionality you have provided would do the job, except that things are slightly offset. For example, your code would in the first instance generate 15 cases of base_size=10, when in fact base_size should = 1 for the first 15 days. Do you see what I mean? Because for the first row, the rel_days = 0, we would repeat base_size=1 0 times.

Comment: Problem fixed, stupidly, of course an offset can be managed by doing something like c(0, array) :)

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the comments.  By concatenating with 0, it can be resolved as you mentioned.